For $x\ge2$ the equation $x\sin x+\cos x=2x-2$ has no solution
As a part of a proof, I need to prove that for $x\ge2$ the equation $x\sin x+\cos x=2x-2$ has no solution. On desmos, I could see the only solution is nearly 1.7 which clearly indicates no solution when $x>2$. I could prove it using two cases (1) when $x\in [2,3]$. and (20) when $x>3$. I am looking for an elegant solution. Thanks in advanced

As both $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ can't be larger than $1$, you automatically see that $x \sin x + \cos x$ can't be larger than $x+1$, so it's soon to be smaller than $2x-2$, once $x$ starts being large enough. Just make a drawing of both graphs, it's quite visible.

Your method looks fine for a proof. Im not sure anything ore elegant exists although I wont say its impossible.

$x \sin x + \cos x = 2x - 2 \iff 2 + \cos x = 2x - x \sin x \iff 2 + \cos x = x(2 - \sin x)$
Now, on the left side of above equation we have some number between $1$ and $3$, also inside brackets we have another number, again between $1$ and $3$, hence, $x$ which multiplies that number inside brackets can not be larger than $2$.

Hereby the graph of the functions $x \sin x + \cos x$, of $2x-2$ and of $x+1$ (that latter is the mentioned upper bound of $x \sin x + \cos x$):

